# Duplication bug on Bounty system

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I'm experiencing the following behavior with the bounty screen:

-The window is duplicated if you click twice on the link:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that's more or less by design. All the other pop-ups we have behave the same way.